# Creating users in SMF from outside

Tags: user-management, smf-forum, smf

I'm working on emedding SMF users into current website, and I need to make mechanism that will automatically register people afer their registration on website. Can anyway suggest me how I can do this, as far as I uderstand that's not possible to do with SSI?

thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SMF are you using? What website are you trying to integrate with?

A commonly requested scenario is tying Wordpress to SMF. There have been several bridges built in the past, but they've been withdrawn due to license compatibility issues. However, if that's what you're looking for *and* you're running SMF 2 and WP 3+, take a look at this brand new mod, which will do what you're asking: [Wordpress 3.0+ User Integration](http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=3008).

Good luck! (And you'll probably get better help on the SMF support forums, which are very active, with a very helpful support team.)

Answer (score 0):

I you are using SMF2.0, the user andre nickatina created an API and an INTEGRATION HOOK intending to integrate/synchronise SMF with your website users.

The API will let you control SMF from your other system.
The INTEGRATION HOOK will let you control your other system from SMF

All info and support can be found on the following link
http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=453008.0

BTW really good support provided by andre nickatina, i use it on my website and works really well, if you want i can pass you my website URL so you can see it in action.

Good Luck!